# datepicker changes dates when december is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery

[here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FYSPJJOIDNZB) you can see a datepicker I want to use.

There is an error clicking on `next month` - if `december` is reached click still changes dates and title of month keeps unchanged.

After that click on `prev month` - first click has the same bug.

I tried with `1`, `11` and `13` inside `if(currPage > 0)` and `if(currPage < 12)` - without success.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if thats what you expected. You should set `<11` condition there, not `<12`. Since you reached 12th month (11th index) you were able to trigger function one more time and increase index.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>MY DATEPICKER</title>
     <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript" > </script>

     <style type="text/css">
      
     </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var currPage = 0; //month
  var year ;
  var day;

  function getVal(e)
  {
    //lert(document.getElementById(e.id).value);
    day = document.getElementById(e.id).value;
    document.getElementById("waha").value = year +"/"+  (currPage + 1)  + "/" + day ;
  }


  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#waha").focus(function()
    {

     getDays(0);
     $("#datepicker").css("display"," block");
     
    }
    );


   $("#next-month").click(function(){
    if(currPage < 11)
    {
     currPage =  currPage+1;
     getDays(currPage);
    }

   });

   $("#prev-month").click(function(){

     if(currPage > 0)
     {
      currPage =  currPage-1;
      getDays(currPage);
     }
   });


   $("#next-y").click(function(){

    $("#year").text(  parseInt($("#year").text())  + 1   )  ;
    getDays(currPage);


   });


   $("#prev-y").click(function(){

   $("#year").text(  parseInt($("#year").text())  - 1   )  ;
     getDays(currPage);

   });   

   

   function getDays(month)
   {

    $("#dt-able").empty();
    var mos=['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','Novemeber','Decemeber']
    var day=['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed' , 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
    year = parseInt($("#year").text());

    $("#month-title").html(mos[month]);

    $("#dt-able").append('<tr>');
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {

     $('#dt-able').append("<td id='dt-head'>"  + day[i] + "</td>");
    }

    $("#dt-able").append('</td>');

    var firstDay = new Date(year,month, 1);
    var lastDay = new Date(year, month+1, 0);
    

  
    var offset = firstDay.getDay();

    var dayCount = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
     $('#dt-able').append("<tr id=row-"+ i +">");
     for(rw = 0; rw < 7; rw++ )
     {
      if(offset == 0)
      {

       $('#' + "row-"+ i).append("<td  id='"  + "cell-" + dayCount+ "'>"
        +   "<input type='button' id ='day_val" +dayCount +"'"+   " onclick='getVal(this)' value= '" +  dayCount + "' >"  + 
         
        '</td>' );
       

       if(dayCount >= lastDay.getDate())
       {
        break;
       }
       dayCount++;
      }else
      {
       $('#' + "row-"+ i).append('<td>' +'</td>' );
        offset--;

      }

  


     }
     $('#dt-able').append('</tr>');

    }
   }


  });

  
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

<input type="text" id="waha" >
<div id="datepicker" style="display:none">
<h4 id="month-title"></h4>
  <input type="button" name="prev-y" value="Prev Year"  id="prev-y" ">
   <span id="year">2017</span> 
  <input type="button" name="next-y" value="Next Year"  id="next-y" ">
 <table id="dt-able" >




<td class="day_val"> </td>


 </table>

 <input type="button" name="prev" value="Prev Mo"  id="prev-month" ">
 <input type="button" name="next" value="Next Mo"  id="next-month" ">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```